# What is the effect of \hsize and \vsize in plain TeX?

Tags: plain-tex, dvi

I was reading the TeXbook. From the instruction I use \hsize=4in and \vsize=4in in the tex program, and generate the output dvi file.

There are several problems.

1. Is the \hsize the horizontal size of the the text or of the page?
2. Neither of the text dimension or the page dimension are square.
3. The dvi output actually has the size of A4, viewed from the program xdvi in Mac OS.

What is going on?

Comment: `\hsize` and `\vsize` define the text block.  however, with `plain.tex` there are some other considerations: the first baseline sits `\topskip` from the top of the text block; if there are descenders in the line that sits at the very bottom of the text block, they are allowed to "hang out".  this could skew your perception of the dimensions.  as for the dvi output size, the original default was letter size, but local installations often redefine that to the local default paper size, most often a4.

Comment: Thank you @barbarabeeton. What local installations do you mean? The TeX distribution?

Comment: yes, the tex distribution; there are various configuration files that can set up a local default different from the original one.  in a comment to the answer by @wipet, you say that the text characters are scaled; that seems very peculiar.  i'm working on a linux system, but using `xdvi`.  that program supports magnification, which is very handy at times, but it's always a good idea to start with "actual intended size".  documentation for `xdvi` should tell you how to control that.

Comment: @barbarabeeton So what do you expect in my output dvi file then? In my case it should be the usual text size, with the text area confined into a roughly 4 by 4 inches. Due to the local default page size being A4, there should be large margins around the text area. Isn't it?

Comment: plain tex always uses 1in above and to the left so if you set a small hsize and vsize and print on a4 then you'd expect large margins at the right and bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roughly speaking, `\hsize` is the size of pieces when paragraph is broken to the lines. This means, that it is the width of these lines. But exceptions exist (`\leftskip`, `\rightskip` for example).

`\vsize` is the size of pieces when the column of the text is broken to the pages (or to more columns at one page). This means that this is the size of `\topskip` plus text without the depth of the last line. The header and footer is not counted here.

No `\hskip`, `\vskip` have a connection to real page dimensions. The box with the text is put to the page with regrads to the left-top corner (where `\voffset` and `\hoffest` play a role), but page dimensions is totally irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks. But the effect on the output seems like the text IS roughly of the size of 4in, instead everything is scaled to A4. Hence the characters are twice as large as before. What causes the scaling?

Comment: @JoeLi that scaling is not the default (if you see it on printing then there is often a setting in the driver to "scale to paper size" but that is unconnected with tex really.)